# Mark every line that ends NOT with specific character in sublime 2

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I have a text that is like this:

```
This first sentence
is split up
on several rows.
While this sentence fits in one row.
```

What I want to have: Get every sentence that ends with "." in a single row.

```
This first sentence is split up on several rows.
While this sentence fits in one row.
```

I tried to mark every line, that ends with "." and to invert the selection but couldn`t figure it out. What is your suggestion to solve my problem?

It might be interesting for everyone who has to edit a text that is pasted out of a .PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a look behind assertion as

```
(?<!\.)\n
```

replace with space

For example http://regex101.com/r/oS2qZ8/1

Comment: Yes, you nailed it! Sorry that I didn`t find that answer for myself. Works perfectly!